# Import the Quandl's harmonized data into r

Tags: r, quandl

I'm looking for a way to import the Quandl's harmonized data into r.

I tried to use Quandl package with:

```
Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COSTOFREVENUE_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29")
```

but with no luck so I tried:

```
Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COST_OF_REVENUE_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29")
```

The error that I got is:

> Requested entity does not exist. This could mean the code does not
>   exist or the parameters you have passed have returned an empty
>   dataset.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo on the page you were looking at.

The call is:

Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COST_OF_REVENUE_TOTAL_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29")

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ray. I guess the typo was with the "_TOTAL_" and that's it?
Also, how can I concatenate several fundamentls Indecators in the same line?